# BCC not hidden on gmail using python smtplib

Tags: python, email, smtplib, bcc

I am working on a python script to send email to my customer with a survey. I will send only one email with all my customers's emails in the BCC field so that I do not need to loop through all the emails. Everything works fine when I tested sending emails to my company's coleagues and also when I sent to my personal email, but whenever I send to a gmail account, the BCC field appears to not be hidden and show all the emails. I found this post [Email Bcc recipients not hidden using Python smtplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042846/email-bcc-recipients-not-hidden-using-python-smtplib) and tried that solution as well, but as I am using a html body email, the emails were shown inside the body. Can anyone help me on this one?

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage


def send_survey_mail():

template_path = 'template.html'
background_path = 'image.png'
button_path = 'image2.png'

try:
    body = open(template_path, 'r')
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['Subject'] = 'Customer Survey'
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(['myemail@domain.com.br', 'myemail2@domain.com'])
    msg['From'] = 'mycompany@mycompany.com.br'
    msg['Bcc'] = 'customer@domain.com'

    text = MIMEText(body.read(), 'html')
    msg.attach(text)

    fp = open(background_path, 'rb')
    img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    fp.close()

    fp2 = open(button_path, 'rb')
    img2 = MIMEImage(fp2.read())
    fp2.close()

    img.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
    msg.attach(img)

    img2.add_header('Content-ID', '<image2>')
    msg.attach(img2)

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtpserver')

    s.sendmail('mycompany@mycompany.com.br',
               ['myemail@domain.com.br', 'myemail2@domain.com', 'customer@domain.com'],
               msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
except Exception as ex:
    raise ex

send_survey_mail()
```

I removed the following line from the code and tried again. Now the email is not sent to my customer's Gmail email.

```
msg['Bcc'] = 'customer@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do not  mention bcc mails in msg['To'] or msg['Cc']. Do it only in **server.sendmail()**

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

from_addr = "your@mail.com"
to_addr = ["to@mail.com", "to2@mail.com"]

msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = from_addr
msg['To'] = to_addr
msg['Subject'] = "SUBJECT"

body = "BODY"

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = "FILE.pdf"
attachment = open('/home/FILE.pdf', "rb")

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('.....', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(from_addr, 'yourpass')
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr + [bcc@mail.com], text)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try *not* to define the `msg['BCC']` field? Setting this field forces it to be included. It is sufficient that the BCC email address is in the sendmail command's destination address list. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546367/python-how-to-send-mail-with-to-cc-and-bcc).

Comment: Yes, I did that same solution on the link, but in my case I need the body to be html, so when I do that way, the email addresses as well the subject appear on the body of the email.

Answer (score 0):

```
MAIL_FROM = default@server.com
MAIL_DL = default@server.com

def send(to, cc, bcc, subject, text, html):
    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    message["Subject"] = subject
    message["From"] = MAIL_FROM
    message["To"] = to
    message["Cc"] = cc + "," + MAIL_DL

    if html is not None:
        body = MIMEText(html, "html")
    else:
        body = MIMEText(text)
    message.attach(body)

    server = smtplib.SMTP(MAIL_SERVER)
    server.set_debuglevel(1)

    server.sendmail(MAIL_DL, to.split(",") + bcc.split(","), message.as_string())
    server.quit()

    return {
        "to": to,
        "cc": cc,
        "bcc": bcc,
        "subject": subject,
        "text": text,
        "html": html,
    }
```